# AG Grid's file styles no longer available in https://unpkg.com/ag-grid-community/dist/styles

Tags: angular, ag-grid-angular

I have angular application using Ag-Grid in produciton for 4 years ago, suddenly few days ago the styles was not there I find I am pointing to

https://unpkg.com/ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-grid.css
https://unpkg.com/ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-theme-balham.css
is there a quick solution to get like download  ag-grid.css and ag-theme-balham.css  in other locations?

Answer (score 2):

The v29 [Changelog](https://ag-grid.com/changelog/?fixVersion=29.0.0) describes why this dist folder has been deleted.

To resolve please follow the [instructions](https://ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/global-style-upgrading-to-v28-css/) from the official docs as the styles are now in a new location.

```
<!-- old path -->
<link
  rel="stylesheet"
  href="https://unpkg.com/ag-grid-community@29.0.0/dist/styles/ag-grid.css" />

<!-- new path -->
<link
  rel="stylesheet"
  href="https://unpkg.com/ag-grid-community@29.0.0/styles/ag-grid.css" />
```

You may want to specify the version explicitly in your unpkg link otherwise when we release new major versions your app will just start trying to use the new version and could break.

Comment: Where does the Changelog address the dist folder deletion? I couldn't find it there. Please include a short quotation with the reason.

Comment: In v29 [Changelog](https://ag-grid.com/changelog/?fixVersion=29.0.0) expand the Release notes and see the Layout & Styling section that explains that we deleted them following v28 still having them for one major to be backwards compatible.